# How to return Tuple in a mock?

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, moq, tuples

I have an method like this:

```
public virtual Tuple<int,int> GetQuantities(Entry entry, CartHelper cartHelper)
{
    //something to do
    return new Tuple<int, int>(minQuantity, maxQuantity);
}
```

and to unit-test it, I write this mock:

```
ProductMock
    .Setup(
        u => u.GetQuantities(It.IsAny<Entry>(), 
        It.IsAny<CartHelper>()))
    .Returns(new Tuple<int,int>(minQuantity, maxQuantity));
```

But this code failed to compile, with this error:

> Argument 1: cannot convert from '`System.Tuple<int,int>`' to
>   '`` System.Tuple`2<int,int> ``'

`` System.Tuple`2 `` suggests me about the "anonymous type" behind the Tuple class, but I can't find what going on behind the scene, and how to fix this issue.

### Edit

Sorry, my bad, I just discovered that our main project is set to .NET 3.5, and it uses Tuple from a custom reference (System.ComponentModel.Composition), and test project is using .NET 4.0, and it use .NET's Tuple class. I don't know how this version-inconsistent come to our solution, but I had to switch to another workaround, instead of using Tuple.

Comment: System.Tuple`2 has nothing to do with anonymous types, it just indicates the one of classes named `Tuple` which has two generic parameters (in same fashion as e.g. System.Collections.Generic.List`1, System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2 etc). `System.Tuple` is, according to MSDN ( http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.tuple.aspx ), a static class, so there could be no instances of System.Tuple, and thus the error you're facing is confusing at least. Hope this helps in some way.

Comment: What mocking framework do you use?

Comment: @Archeg: We're using Moq

Comment: Are you using .NET 4's Tuple class? Are you linking in any nonstandard Tuple implementations for use with older .NET versions?

Comment: @TrueWill: I'm using .NET 4.0 class

Answer (score 13):

```
var tupletoReturn=Tuple.Create<int, int>(51, 57);

ProductMock.Setup(u => u.GetQuantities(It.IsAny<Entry>(), It.IsAny<CartHelper>())).Returns(tupletoReturn);
```

if works for me

```
public class MyClass
    {
        public virtual Tuple<int, int> GetQuantities(Entry entry, CartHelper cartHelper)
        {

            return new Tuple<int, int>(0, 0);
        }
    }

    [TestFixture]
    public class Test
    {
        [Test]
        public void TestMethod()
        {
            var tupleToReturn = Tuple.Create<int, int>(10, 20);
            Mock<MyClass> p = new Mock<MyClass>();
            p.Setup(
           u => u.GetQuantities(It.IsAny<Entry>(),
                   It.IsAny<CartHelper>()))
                      .Returns(tupleToReturn);


        }
    }
```

Comment: This is to return a Task for Tuple   ---- https://jamesradley.co.uk/2020/08/05/mock-a-return-type-of-task-and-tuple-with-moq/