# Mock a Tuple List c#

Tags: c#, moq

New to Moq

Trying to mock an update method that passes a list of thisMovieIndexEntries of type below. Please correct me where I doing it wrong.

Example thisMovieIndexEntry type:

```
 (double IsAtLoc, IMovieIndexEntry<double> MovieIndexEntry) thisMovieIndexEntry;
```

Mocking UpdateIndexAtLocationAsync method using this code below:

```
 mockMovieIndProvider.Setup(p => p.UpdateIndexAtLocationAsync(List<It.IsAny<double>(),It.IsAny<IMovieIndexEntry<double>>()>()).Throws(new MyException());
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to return Tuple in a mock?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9291542/how-to-return-tuple-in-a-mock)

Comment: Do you mean something like `It.IsAny<(double, IMovieIndexEntry<double>)>`?

Comment: @DavidG : Nope, that does not work :(

Comment: "doesn't work" in what way? We need more details.

Comment: @DavidG: I am trying to send a list of thisMovieIndexEntries with It.IsAny for both IsAtLoc and MovieIndexEntry

Comment: Extending @DavidG's comment, I think It.IsAny<List<(double, IMovieIndexEntry<double>)>>() should work.

Comment: Glad to know it worked. It was @DavidG who solved it actually. I just extended it a bit.