# Mocking a call to method with Tuple parameter

Tags: c#, unit-testing, tuples, moq

I have a class which exposes a public method with tuple as parameter, definition as below -

```
public interface IRandomInterface
{
    void FunctionOne((int paramOne, int paramTwo) paramTuple, int paramThree);
}

public class SomeRandomClass:IRandomInterface
{
    public void FunctionOne((int paramOne, int paramTwo) paramTuple, int paramThree)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Value of paramOne is " + Convert.ToString(paramTuple.paramOne));
        Console.WriteLine("Value of paramTwo is " + Convert.ToString(paramTuple.paramTwo));
        Console.WriteLine("Value of paramThree is " + Convert.ToString(paramThree));
    }
}
```

This class is being consumed by another, its definition as below -

```
public class AnotherClass
{
    private IRandomInterface _randomInterface;

    public AnotherClass(IRandomInterface randomInterface)
    {
        _randomInterface = randomInterface;
    }

    public void MethodOne()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Some random logic here....");
        Console.WriteLine("...and then call to SomeRandomClass.FunctionOne");
        _randomInterface.FunctionOne((1,2),3);
    }
}
```

How do I mock the dependency when testing AnotherClass? I have tried this

```
[Fact]
public void Test1()
{
    //Arrange
    Mock<IRandomInterface> _randomInterfaceMock = new Mock<IRandomInterface>();
    _randomInterfaceMock.Setup(r => r.FunctionOne((It.IsAny<int>,It.IsAny<int>), 3));
    AnotherClass instance = new AnotherClass(_randomInterfaceMock.Object);
    
    //Act
    instance.MethodOne();
    
    //Assert...
}
```

Unfortunately compiler does not like it. I get the error CS1503:

> Argument 1: cannot convert from '(method group, method group)' to '(int paramOne, int paramTwo)' error.

I have seen this post - [Mock a Tuple List c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67670618/mock-a-tuple-list-c-sharp) which is on similar lines, but didnt solve the problem for me (and there is no clearly marked answer in it), hence posting this question.

Comment: `It.IsAny<int>()` ? You're missing the `()`. If that doesn't work, you may have to do `It.IsAny<(int, int)>()` instead of `(It.IsAny<int>(), It.IsAny<int>())`

Comment: For _randomInterfaceMock.Setup(r => r.FunctionOne((It.IsAny<int>(),It.IsAny<int>()), 3)); it gives compiler error CS8143:An expression tree may not contain a tuple literal.

Comment: _randomInterfaceMock.Setup(r => r.FunctionOne((It.IsAny<int, int>()), 3)); does not work either,CS0305 : Using the generic method 'It.IsAny<TValue>()' requires 1 type arguments.

Comment: You didn't read my comment properly. `It.IsAny<(int, int)>()`. You're missing a `(` and a `)`.

Comment: @canton7 I think I have tried all permutations and combinations with brackets. Can you please type in the entire line you think it should be? Just wondering, VS should be intelligent enough to be able to identify missing brackets, rather than misleading a user into an error about some compilation error...?

Comment: `r.FunctionOne(It.IsAny<(int, int)>(), 3)`. I don't follow: the compilation error you posted above clearly explains what was wrong: you called `It.IsAny<int, int>()` which passes two generic type argument to the `It.IsAny` method, but the method only takes one generic type argument, which the error clearly explains.